# Chrome tab name shows up in task manager

Tags: google-chrome

Today I noticed that the name of a Google chrome tab shows up in the windows task manager. In a high security environment this could be a problem (maybe using some in house site etc.) Is there a way to prevent chrome from showing the tab name in task manager?
[image: A picture showing information leaking into task manager]

Comment: Don't think so. BTW, addons can show up there also.

Comment: I wouldn't what someone to see my "super secret information" when I visit porn sites, so this is interesting for me also :).